# Meteor how to get the result of Collection.update on success or failure?

Tags: meteor

I have a collection that is getting updated in an event handler and which is updating the collection and I would like to get the result of the update if it was a success or failure so I can do some logic based on its result. i.e. reset session values etc.

I have always been just testing the db action itself inside of an if block for inserts which worked fine however this does not seem to be working for update.

```
Template.customers_update.events({
'click a#cancel, click button#close' : function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Session.set("editCustomer", false);
    Session.set("customerId", null);
},

'click input[type=submit], submit form#create_customer' : function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var customer_name = $("#customer_name").val();
    var customer_address = $("#customer_address").val();
    var customer_city = $("#customer_city").val();
    var customer_state = $("#customer_state").val();
    var customer_zip = $("#customer_zip").val();
    var customer_phone = $("#customer_phone").val();
    var customer_fax = $("#customer_fax").val();
    var customer_eda = $("#eda_number").val();
    var customer_duns = $("#duns_number").val();

    if (Customers.update(Session.get("customerId"), {$set: {user_id: Meteor.user()._id, name: customer_name, address: customer_address, city: customer_city, state: customer_state, zip: customer_zip, phone: customer_phone, fax: customer_fax, eda_number: customer_eda, duns_number: customer_duns}})) {
        console.log("Update Sucsess");
        Session.set("editCustomer", false);
        Session.set("customerId", null);

   }
 }
});
```

and in the server it is set to allow and return true

```
Customers.allow({
insert: function (userID, customer) {
        return userID === customer.user_id;
  },

update: function (userID, customer) {
    return userID === customer.user_id;
},

remove: function (userID, customer) {
    return userID === customer.user_id;
}

});
```

Comment: Why do you think `update` should return `true` in the first place? It doesn't say so in the docs.

Comment: in the allow rules im telling it to return the result of userID === customer.user_id which is true, hence the update is working i.e. if it would be falsy it would fail also it works that way insert which works as expected

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#allow

Comment: its checking the result of insert which is either true or false based on the rules set in collection.allow

Comment: The allow rule has nothing to do with the return value of `update`. On the client `update` returns immediately. It has not way of knowing if it was allowed or rejected. Only via callback.

Comment: Is this code on the server or the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the third argument `callback` ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#update))

> **callback** Function
>
> Optional. If present, called with an error object as its argument.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is probably not working because the .update() only throws an exception on the server.  From the docs:

> On the server, if you don't provide a callback, then update blocks until the database  acknowledges the write, or throws an exception if something went wrong. If you do provide a callback, update returns immediately. Once the update completes, the callback is called with a single error argument in the case of failure, or no arguments if the update was successful.
>
> On the client, update never blocks. If you do not provide a callback and the update fails on the server, then Meteor will log a warning to the console. If you provide a callback, Meteor will call that function with an error argument if there was an error, or no arguments if the update was successful.

Change it to:

```
var updateQuery = {$set: {user_id: Meteor.user()._id, name: customer_name, address: customer_address, city: customer_city, state: customer_state, zip: customer_zip, phone: customer_phone, fax: customer_fax, eda_number: customer_eda, duns_number: customer_duns}}
Customers.update(Session.get("customerId"), updateQuery, function (error) {
    //on error do this
});
```